# Inserting values in database Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a **Product** table with columns `Product_Id(pk), Name, Price, description, CategoryId, SubCategoryId, SubSubCategoryId`

and another **Category** table with columns `CategoryId(pk), CategoryName, ParentId`.

and another table **ProductAttributesValues** with columns `ProductAttributeValueId(pk), ProductId(fk), Size, Quantity`

I've this data in my category table:

```
CategoryId | CategoryName | ParentId
    1      |   Clothing   |   NULL
    2      |   Computing  |   NULL
    3      |     Books    |   NULL
    4      |    Men's     |   1
    5      |    Women's   |   1
    6      |     Kid's    |   1
    7      |    Laptops   |   2
    8      |   Desktops   |   2
    9      |    Shirts    |   4
    10     |     Tops     |   5
    11     |   Macbooks   |   7
    11     |  Ultrabooks  |   7
```

As you can see Category with `NULL` value is Parent and other are their child and so on. Like: **Category** Clothing > **SubCategory** Men's > **SubSubCategory** Shirts

**Product.cs**

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SubSubCategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductAttributeValues.cs**

```
public partial class ProductAttributeValues
{
    public int ProductAttributeValueId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Size {get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ProductAttributesViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? SubSubCategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Sizes { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddProduct(ProductAttributesViewModel newRecord)
    {
      IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categories = db.Categories.Where(w => w.ParentId == null).Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        });
        ViewBag.CategoryId = categories;

                   var product = new Product
                    {
                        Name = newRecord.Name,
                        CategoryId = newRecord.CategoryId,
                        SubCategoryId = newRecord.SubCategoryId,
                        SubSubCategoryId = newRecord.SubSubCategoryId,
                        Description = newRecord.Description,
                        Price = newRecord.Price,
                        Quantity = newRecord.Quantity
                    };

                    var productattributevalues = new ProductAttributeValue
                    {
                        ProductId = newRecord.ProductId,
                        Size = newRecord.Size
                        Quantity = newRecord.Stock
                    };
                    db.Products.Add(product);
                    db.ProductAttributeValues.Add(productattributevalues);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
     }
```

**View**

```
@model ProjectABC.ViewModels.ProductAttributesViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddProduct", "Store", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal col-md-12", role = "form" }))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", data_val_required = "required" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, String.Empty, new {onchange="jsFunction(this.value);", @class = "col-xs-8 control-label CssCategory" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubCategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "col-xs-8 control-label" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubSubCategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "col-xs-8 control-label CssSubSubCategory" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quantity, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Create Product" />
            </div>
        </div>
   }
```

**PROBLEM**

All values from fields are inserted successfully in both Product and ProductAttributesValues tables but only SubCategoryId and SubSubCategoryId is NULL in product table. I've created these subcategory and subsubcategor columns in Product table so I can perform Searching through this.

I've populated 3 dropdownlist for category, subcategory and subsubcategory, When I select any category, CategoryId is popedup using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsFunction(value) {
    alert(value);
}
```

but not storing subcategoryId and subsubcategoryId value in product table. All remaining fields are stored except these two.

Comment: I've posted a possible answer.

Comment: Did you inspect the `newRecord`? Does it contain any value for `SubCategoryId` and `SubSubCategoryId ` ?

Comment: @MahbuburRahman its null. but when I change the value from dropdownlist, I got the ID in alertbox through script

Comment: You get because you are using the dropdown of category for both subcategory and subsubcategory.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you used the same `SELECT` HTML tag element for both of them.

The problem is with `@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId"` should be different for both of them.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubCategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "col-xs-8 control-label" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubSubCategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "col-xs-8 control-label CssSubSubCategory" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Should be:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubCategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">    
        @Html.DropDownList("SubCategoryId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "col-xs-8 control-label" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SubSubCategoryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("SubSubCategoryId", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "col-xs-8 control-label CssSubSubCategory" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've changed what you said but now its giving an error,
`There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SubCategoryId'.`

Comment: I got it working. I just changed the 2 words like you did and also I did this in my GET method,

`ViewBag.SubCategoryId = categories; ..            ViewBag.SubSubCategoryId = categories;`

Comment: Using `ViewBag` for this is not a good idea. Use a model class that describes the Form model.

Answer (score 1):

First generate the select list for subcategory and subsubcategory from controller :

`ViewBag.SubCategoryId= db.Categories.Where(w => w.ParentId == null).Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.SubCategoryId.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        });
ViewBag.SubSubCategoryId= db.Categories.Where(w => w.ParentId == null).Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.SubSubCategoryId.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        });`

Then follow the answer of @Orel Eraki.